# Can I receive FM radio signal via Headphone port on Laptop?

Tags: audio, headphones, radio

My Laptop has no built-in FM Receiver. But I see that Android phones (normally) receives FM Signal through the headphone port. As long as I know they have built-in  FM demodulator (or something similar) to work.

My question is, (I don't have enough idea on hardware though) is it possible to receive FM signal through headphone port (like headphone mic-audio) and process the signal using the CPU (like a software decoder) ?

Comment: FM receivers used to be available with USB interfaces and software to allow playing, scheduling and recording on a computer, but I haven't noticed any for sale recently. Alternatively, you can tune to the radio channels on an external USB TV receiver.

Comment: Just an FYI here for clarification, Android phones do not use the headphone port as an FM receiver, that is built into the SOC (System On a Chip) or a dedicated FM receiver chip on the main board, the headset port (actually the wires of the headset) are used as an FM antenna to receive the signal.

Answer (score 4):

No. Laptops do not offer a build-in FM decoder.

A SoC (System on a Chip) usually has them, but their reception is too weak. The headphone is then used as an antenna, which is why it works for phones.

That said, if your laptop has internet, you can use an online radio station and stream the radio to you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive FM signals you need a high tech piece of equipment called a radio.

Yep.  A radio, which your laptop doesnt have, but many phones do.  Phones use the headphone line as the antenna, it has nothing to do with other hardware.

Comment: "A radio" is incorrect - you presumably mean a "receiver picking up appropriate bands". I'm u aware if any modern laptop that does not have a built in "radio" - as the ability to handle radio is required for WIFI - only not neccessarily at the required frequencies, and not analog"

Answer (score 0):

yes your sound card can receive wave radios and you can process that, but fm has a frequency of 87-108 Mhz and your device works with maximum 96Khz, fm has high frequency and needs a short antena for receive, low frequencies needs monstruos antenas or parabólicas to receive his signal, start searching sdr on google